# Use 3rd party token for laravel CSRF token

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I'm trying to implement BPC and cache an entire page and show the cached version to user in the browser.

My problem is I don't want to make an ajax call to the server and fill the CSRF token field.

Is there a way I can use a trusted 3rd party token generation and override the VerifyCsrfToken middleware to authenticate the 3rd pary token generation?

I want users to be able to make post request without me having to make a hit to the server to fetched the new csrf token.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but what is BPC? Maybe another solution is caching the pages with Laravel with a package, like https://github.com/JosephSilber/page-cache?

Comment: @Tim BPC is Base Page Caching. I'm caching the page at CDN level and based on certains rules I show the page from the cache or show the page from the server.